# How to fix not found error on angular app deployed on GCP

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, single-page-application

I have successfully deployed my angular app on GCP. It works fine but if I try to refresh the page after navigation, I get the following:

> Error: Not Found 
>   The requested URL /feed was not found on this server.

I tried to fix the problem by editing the app.yaml configuration but it didn't work. What should I do to the app.yaml file in order to allow refreshed pages to be accessed?

Comment: what you are using on gcp to deploy your app, i mean which server?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **.htaccess** file in the base working directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

In your route config have,

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})

or configure your server to return index.html in case of 404.

Comment: The problem is not with angular, on my local machine I can open all routes. The problem is with GCP configuration.

Comment: Then it would be a good point to [open a case with GCP](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) and have an engineer take a closer look into the issue. Otherwise, provide a redacted version of the app.yaml used to deploy the application.